# Android TextView go over the toolbar

Tags: android

i have problem that when i am using a text view 
the text from the list view come over my toolbar 
i don't know what to do , please help me
because i want to use later to toolbar for make 
search filter .
thanks to all the helpers if you need me to add my style file or something please let me know !

[image]

activity xml :

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"

    tools:context=".MainActivity" >

    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/listView"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent" >
    </ListView>

</LinearLayout>
```

custom list xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:background="#dee2e2">

    <LinearLayout
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textSize="25dp"
            android:text="TextView" />

        <LinearLayout
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:gravity="center_horizontal">

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
                android:text="Small Text"
                android:id="@+id/textView3"
                android:layout_marginLeft="10dp" />

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
                android:text="Small Text"
                android:id="@+id/textView4"
                android:layout_marginLeft="10dp" />

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
                android:text="Small Text"
                android:id="@+id/textView5"
                android:layout_marginLeft="10dp" />

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
                android:text="Small Text"
                android:id="@+id/textView6"
                android:layout_marginLeft="10dp" />
        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="right"
            android:gravity="center_horizontal">

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
                android:text="Small Text"
                android:id="@+id/textView7"
                android:layout_marginLeft="10dp" />

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
                android:text="Small Text"
                android:id="@+id/textView8"
                android:layout_marginLeft="10dp" />

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
                android:text="Small Text"
                android:id="@+id/textView9"
                android:layout_marginLeft="10dp" />

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
                android:text="Small Text"
                android:id="@+id/textView10"
                android:layout_marginLeft="10dp" />
        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="right"
            android:gravity="center_horizontal">

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
                android:text="Small Text"
                android:id="@+id/textView11"
                android:layout_marginLeft="10dp" />

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
                android:text="Small Text"
                android:id="@+id/textView12"
                android:layout_marginLeft="10dp" />

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
                android:text="Small Text"
                android:id="@+id/textView13"
                android:layout_marginLeft="10dp" />

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
                android:text="Small Text"
                android:id="@+id/textView14"
                android:layout_marginLeft="10dp" />
        </LinearLayout>

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/imageView1"
            android:layout_width="120dp"
            android:layout_height="120dp"
            android:src="@drawable/edit_icon"
            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:layout_margin="10dp" />

        <LinearLayout
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:gravity="center_horizontal">

            <ImageView
                android:layout_width="65dp"
                android:layout_height="65dp"
                android:id="@+id/imageView"
                android:src="@drawable/edit_icon"
                android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
                android:layout_margin="5dp" />

            <ImageView
                android:layout_width="65dp"
                android:layout_height="65dp"
                android:id="@+id/imageView2"
                android:src="@drawable/edit_icon"
                android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
                android:layout_margin="5dp" />

            <ImageView
                android:layout_width="65dp"
                android:layout_height="65dp"
                android:id="@+id/imageView3"
                android:src="@drawable/edit_icon"
                android:layout_marginBottom="20dp"
                android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="5dp" />

            <ImageView
                android:layout_width="65dp"
                android:layout_height="65dp"
                android:id="@+id/imageView4"
                android:src="@drawable/edit_icon"
                android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
                android:layout_margin="5dp" />

            <ImageView
                android:layout_width="65dp"
                android:layout_height="65dp"
                android:id="@+id/imageView5"
                android:src="@drawable/edit_icon"
                android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
                android:layout_margin="5dp" />
        </LinearLayout>

    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Can you post your XML code as well.

Comment: add TY for Reference

Comment: did you run it on another device than genymotion emulator

Comment: if i put it in real device i can see the toolbar but its cut off the list view